# convert string to time in Stata

Tags: string, time, format, stata

I have the following time stamps in string format in my Stata file. How do I convert this into a time format?

The data is in HH:MM:SS format with an additional ".000000" behind.

```
TIME
21:17:47.000000
17:30:14.000000
10:09:44.000000
09:24:32.000000
15:17:41.000000
```

Comment: What code did you try? No visible research effort.

Answer (score 0):

The only twist over standard code here is an apparent need to ignore the implied microsecond precision. The code here takes the example literally in working with exact seconds only. If you really have millisecond precision, use more characters from the string.

```
. clear 

. input str15 stime 

               stime
  1. "21:17:47.000000"
  2. "17:30:14.000000"
  3. "10:09:44.000000"
  4. "09:24:32.000000"
  5. "15:17:41.000000"
  6. end 

. gen double ntime = clock(substr(stime, 1, 8), "hms") 

. format ntime %tcHH:MM:ss 

. list 

     +----------------------------+
     |           stime      ntime |
     |----------------------------|
  1. | 21:17:47.000000   21:17:47 |
  2. | 17:30:14.000000   17:30:14 |
  3. | 10:09:44.000000   10:09:44 |
  4. | 09:24:32.000000   09:24:32 |
  5. | 15:17:41.000000   15:17:41 |
     +----------------------------+
```